# É correto usar tag c e c++ quando a pergunta refere-se apenas a c++?

Tags: debate

Ao meu ver as duas linguagens são diferentes e por esse motivo não deve ser especificado ambas as tags, porém eu vi isso ocorrer em diversas perguntas.

Ao meu ver isso torna mais dificil a filtragem quando necessitamos pesquisar por algo exclusivamente em uma ou outra linguagem.

Neste caso, devo fazer edição nestas postagens?

Caso queiram ver alguns exemplos: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%20c%2b%2b

Comment: Acho que nunca vi um caso desses. O que mais vejo é o contrário: praticamente sempre que tem c e c++, é uma pergunta sobre C.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Na [wiki de tag do c](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info) tem o seguinte:

> #### É C, C++ ou ambos?
>
> Esta tag é para questões relacionadas com a C, não [c++](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). Em alguns casos, você pode estar trabalhando com ambos e aplicar ambas as tags é inteiramente apropriado. No entanto, por favor, não use ambas as tags em um esforço para ajudar a sua pergunta chegar a um público mais vasto. Afinal, as respostas de C++ não ajudam a resolver o problema em C, e boas respostas C, muitas vezes não descrevem a melhor abordagem em C++.

Usar [c](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) quando a pergunta claramente trata apenas de C++ é errado. Pode editar sim.

> **Nota:** Se for para editar a pergunta, procure ver se tem algum outro ponto a melhorar. Evite fazer edições muito pequenas deixando passar algo gritante.
>
> E quando for editar uma grande quantidade de perguntas, especialmente perguntas antigas/mortas, convêm evitar os horários de maior movimento do site. Ou então ir editando aos poucos. Isso para não poluir a homepage do site, que mostra as atividades recentes. Você pode acabar jogando uma pergunta recém criada na segunda página.

Comment: A nota merece um `>` também, pois é bastante pertinente. +1

Comment: Eu costumava sempre editar removendo a tag c++, mas uma vez a edição foi revertida por um medalhista de ouro nessas tags. Depois disso, fiquei meio receoso. Gosto de C++ mas não muito de C, então essa mistura me incomoda um pouco.