# Existe consenso em relação a perguntas sobre C marcadas com a tag C++?

Tags: debate, tags

Baseando-me [nessa pergunta no meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1579/%C3%89-correto-usar-tag-c-e-c-quando-a-pergunta-refere-se-apenas-a-c), eu estava mais confiante de que poderia continuar o meu hábito de orientar usuários a não marcar perguntas com a tag "c++" quando a pergunta é sobre C (comportamento que havia causado uma reversão de edição em uma ocasião).

As minhas justificativas são as que foram mencionadas na resposta à pergunta, vindas da Wiki da tag e mais algumas:

**1)** A exemplo do SOEn, quando um usuário de C++ usa idiomas não muito bem vistos por uma provável familiaridade com C (`malloc`/`free`, `NULL`, ponteiros onde cabem referências etc.), a tendência é em, além de responder a pergunta, educar o(a) AP quanto à forma C++ de resolver o problema. Se a resposta esperada é em C, esse esforço é inútil.

**2)** Um programador C que não entende nada de C++ pode acumular medalhas e mais medalhas em C++, o que acredito não ser desejável.

**3)** Isso não acontece em outras tags. Se alguém usar a tag TypeScript em conjunto com a tag JavaScript e usar código que dá a entender que não sabe a diferença (e nunca usou TypeScript), certamente a tag seria retirada.

Mas hoje [aconteceu essa situação novamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/142753/como-setar-uma-struct-como-null-em-c?noredirect=1#comment295551_142753).

Temos um consenso sobre o que fazer ou não fazer?

Comment: A meu ver é lógico, C++ é uma coisa C é outra, com excepção de alguns casos raros em que se possa usar as duas acho que se deve alertar para  o uso indevido. É quase como usar a tag Java sempre que se pergunta sobre Android, é certo pode ser um problema Java, mas pode também não ser. No caso de C e C++ são mais as coisas que os separam do que as que os juntam, no que toca a perguntas, claro.

Comment: @PabloAlmeida pode fazer as honras: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/142791/101

Comment: Acredito que com exceção dos casos onde a solução em C não atenda as  necessidades da pergunta em C++. Uma reposta em C para C++ é válida assim como a marcação da tag, pois muitas das respostas em C servem para C++ e quem tem o habito de responder perguntas segundo a tag as tags monitoradas poderá ver a pergunta tanto se estiver monitorando C como C++ e poderá contribuir com resposta. Acho que o fato de se preocupar com a pessoa acumular medalha e C++ por ter respondido em C não deve ser fator preocupante, mas sim a qualidade das resposta.

Answer (score 12):

Realmente esse é um caso que merece um cuidado especial porque a pergunta pode ser útil para as duas *tags* ou não.

Em praticamente todo caso que pode fazem em C, pode fazer em C++. Se algo exige um recurso do C++, a *tag* C muito provavelmente não é adequada. O contrário não é tão verdadeiro.

Várias soluções para C servem muito bem para C++ e ter a pergunta descoberta entre as de C++ é algo interessante. Não tudo, claro. Há diferenças de estilo da linguagem em vários pontos.

O AP pode aceitar uma resposta usando uma ou outra solução. Se ele colocou a *tag*, é possível que ele queira ambas, ou serve qualquer uma delas. Também pode ter colocado inadvertidamente. Então o ideal é perguntar antes de fazer uma alteração, se achar que deve aletrar.

Edições devem melhorar algo mas não mudar a intenção do autor. Por isso eu reverti a edição feita e perguntei ao autor, não havia uma base sólida indicando que era o que ele queria. Imediatamente depois de reverter, me ocorreu que deveria ter perguntado antes.

Editar porque gosta das coisas de um jeito não quer dizer que beneficia a comunidade. Tem que analisar o caso e ver se cabe ou não. Tem que ver se é o que o autor quer. A pergunta até pertence à comunidade, mas não podemos editar o que o autor colocou, mudando a sua intenção, sem ter certeza de que ele quer aquilo.

Comment: Concordo com tudo o que disse no último parágrafo. É só que, na minha visão, estava bem claro que a intenção do autor era que as respostas fossem em C (por causa do título, não só do estilo). Em muitos casos no quais vejo esse tipo de coisa, realmente apenas pergunto o motivo da tag C++. Infelizmente, raramente o AP responde.

Comment: Eu mesmo já errei, confundindo as duas(iniciante '-'), e concordo com você @bigown, perguntar antes de fazer alguma alteração duvidosa para evitar futuros problemas na pergunta. Creio eu que seja um erro comum entre os iniciantes, C C# e C++ realmente são parecidas para quem nunca "tocou" nelas, digo isso por experiencia própria.

Comment: Apesar da aperente dualidade entre C e C++, eu não concordo que o que se faz em C pode se fazer em C++. O que é idiomática em C não quer dizer que é idiomática em C++. Ao se deixar a impressão que pode ter essa interoperabilidade entre elas, acaba que começa a dar a impressão que o que se faz em C é o jeito correto em C++, o que não é verdade. Exemplo, em C++ não é idiomático usar pontieiros "crus", enquanto em C isso é o correto de se fazer.

Comment: @Amadeus o ideal é uma coisa, o que as pessoas fazem é outra. Eu entendo sua vontade em fazer o ideal, eu também tento, tanto que sempre escrevo isso nas minhas respostas, mas a grande maioria das perguntas insistem em misturar as coisas, não podemos impor ao usuário nossas vontades, só alertar. Inclusive há controvérsias do que é idiomático ou não em muitos casos, ainda que em vários sejam mais ou menos consenso.

Comment: @bigown Acho que a gente sempre deve buscar o ideal. Talvez a quantidade de perguntas em C++ não seja tão relevante para justificar uma separação (que seria o correto), mas acho que é mais fácil doutrinar do jeito correto no início, do que corrigir depois no futuro